# Why do parentheses work in SELECT queries but no sub queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why is this a valid query

```
SELECT T.A FROM 
 (SELECT A, B  
  FROM  test) T ;
```

and this:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT(A,B)
      FROM  test);
```

but not this:

```
SELECT T.A FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT(A, B)  
  FROM  test) T ;
```

(specifically in postgresql,  but I suspect other sql too)?

UPDATE:

Postgres fails with:

```
ERROR:  column t.a does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT T.A FROM
```

Changing the query to

```
SELECT T.A FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT A, B  
  FROM  test) T ;
```

succeeds, where

```
SELECT T.A FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT (A, B)  
  FROM  test) T ;
```

fails. Why?

Comment: AFAIK it sounds like a valid query (Similar one worked in MySQL). What is the error that you face?

Comment: What error are you getting?  This should be valid syntax: `select a from (select distinct a, b from test) t`...

Comment: `DISTINCT` has nothing to do with it. Compare the output of `SELECT a,b` and `SELECT (a,b)`.

Comment: Thanks -- have updated the title and the question

Comment: `(a,b)` create an [anonymous record with two elements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). You should not use that unless you _really_ know that you want that and what you are doing. As a general rule: do not put columns in the select list in parentheses. In Postgres this does something different and for every other DBMS it's simply useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
SELECT T.A FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT(A, B)  
  FROM  test) T ;
```

Your `(A,B)` syntax is causing that to be returned as a `record` datatype.  As such your subquery (T) sees rows of an anonymous record coming back, not individual fields A and B.

Without the parentheses, they are treated like normal fields, which appears to be what you want.

Comment: Is an excellent answer. Discussion of expression types is missing from almost every tutorial and reference doc I've found and is key to avoiding stumbling around. Thank you.

Comment: @user48956 `distinct (a,b)` is **not** a good idea in Postgres. `(a,b)` generates an anonymous record (as hambone pointed out). Don't do that unless you _really_ want to create a single record with two elements. Using `distinct a,b` is the **much** better solution in this case.

Comment: @hambone: a bit nitpicking: "*As such your subquery (T) sees rows coming back*" - every subquery returns rows. This one returns rows with a single column. As opposed to rows with two columns when the useless parentheses are left out

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- you are right; I actually used the overly generic word `row` in my original post, which @NickBarnes appropriately fixed to `record`.  I'll correct the post -- thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to assign an alias from your sub-query otherwise it couldn't identify the column name from your first seq query...

```
  SELECT T.A FROM 
     (SELECT DISTINCT(A, B) AS A
      FROM  test) T ;
```

Comment: you can diagnosis with the execution plan and you will see your subquery sort the rows coming back but ambiguous column name (it doesnt know what name should be..), so you have to explicit name the `A` in order to make it work.

Comment: `(a,b)` is a single column in Postgres. `a,b` are two columns.